# If a field contains odd nth roots of unity, it contains 2nth roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Clearly, if $\zeta_{n}$ is a root of unity for $n$ odd, then $\zeta_{n}^{2}$ is also a primitive $n$th root, since $(n, 2) = 1$. Hence, $\zeta_{n}$ is a $2n$th root of unity. But how do I know all the $2n$th roots are in this field, including the ones that aren't $n$th roots?

Comment: They're not. For example, try $n=3$.

Comment: Really? The exact wording of the question is "Prove that if a field contains the $n$th roots of unity for $n$ odd, then it also contains the $2n$th roots of unity."

Comment: If $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity, then $-\zeta_n$ is a primitive $2n^{th}$ root (when $n$ is odd of course).

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. I was thinking about the group, not the field.

Comment: I see lulu, so because the field contains all inverses, it's sufficient to prove that result.

Comment: If $n$-th root of unity means the roots of $X^n-1$ then see Robert's answer. If it means primitive $n$-roots of unity, then see lulu's comment, provided the characteristic is not $2$ (in which case primitive $2n$-th roots of unity don't exist).

Answer (score 5):

$X^{2n}-1 = (X^n - 1)(X^n+1)$, so any $2n$'th root of unity that is not an $n$'th root of unity is a root of $X^n + 1$.  But if $n$ is odd, that is $-Y^n + 1$ where $Y = -X$.

Comment: Oh, right, I see this because we can rewrite it by pulling out the negative: $-((\frac{x}{-1})^{n} - 1)$, but this only works because we're dealing with an odd power of -1.

Comment: This answer really needs to address the failure in characteristic $2$.

Comment: What failure?  In characteristic $2$, this says that any $2n$'th root of unity is an $n$'th root of unity.

Answer (score -1):

As we know the formula [Q[]:Q]=$\phi(n)$ so with similar argument $[Q[_{2n}]:Q]$=$\phi(2n)$ as (2,n)=1 so $\phi(2n)=\phi(n)$